# Python, build dict from a list with certain items as keys and items in between as values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension, index-error

I have a text file broken into a list of strings in the format:

```
['DATE','NAME', 'RT','1A','541','09947','199407',552','09949','BOON','101C','SMITH','00321','1553678','1851243','561','559','004789',1749201',ANDERSON']
```

I would like to create a dict using the items where item[0:-1].isdigit() and item[-1].isalpha(), so in the example above this would be 1A and 101C. I then want to add only the items that are int(item.isdigit()) > 100000 where the items fit this criteria are assembled into a new list via a for loop (or maybe a while loop) until the loop hits the next key value.

The result would be dct = `{'1A': ['199407'], '101C':['1553678','1851243','1749201']}`

I'm currently geting an index error despite putting in a while condition to break once the iterations reach the length of the items in the keys list. Before getting this error, I was indexing the values differently and getting an empty dict. I'm expecting to get another empty dict once the index error is fixed.

Here's my code:

```
# create a list of the dictionary keys to find values in 1A format
# in order to avoid key error when building dict, do not add duplicate 
# values to list. Needs to be a list andd not tuple so it can be indexed

for line in lines:
    if line[0:-1].isdigit() and line[-1].isalpha() and line not in keys:
        keys.append(line)

print str(keys) + " " + str(len(keys))


# build a list of values for each item in keys. Should find the first
# key and check if a converted string to number is > 100000. If it is
# the value is appended to the valLst. If the next key is encountered
# the nested loop breaks and valLst is added to the current key. The 
# primary loop moves to the next key while the nested loop should only 
# consider items between the current primary iterable and the next.

passes = 0
while passes <=len(keys): # exit loop before index error
    for key in keys:
        passes += 1 
        curKey = keys.index(key) # current primary iterable position 
        nextKey = curKey + 1 # next primary iterable position
        print "Passes: " + str(passes)
        valLst = [] # empty list for dct values--resets after nested loop break
        for line in lines: #iterate through text
            if line == keys[nextKey]: # the next key value is encountered in text
                break
                dict[key] = valLst # valList added to current dict key
            curLine = lines.index(line) # start at current key value found in text
            if curLine == key: # find current key in text
                nextLine = curLine + 1 # get index of next value after current key in text
                val = lines[nextLine] # next text value
                if val.isdigit(): #append value to valLst if it is > 100000
                    num = int(val)
                    if num > 100000:
                        valLst.append(num)
```

Here is my current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\PDF_Extractor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cStringIO import StringIO
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've been looking into list comprehensions but haven't grasped them well enough to apply one in this situation. Am I going in the right direction with the above code or is there a list comprehension approach I could take that would be something like:

```
valLst = {key for keys in lines for line in line if line == key and int(line.isdigit()) > 100000 valLst.append(line)}
```

Comment: I'm slowing beginning to understand what you're trying to do. Before `'1851243'` there is `'1553678'`, which is greater than `100,000`, why don't you include that number and get `'101C':['1553678', '1851243','1749201']}`?

Comment: @ downshift oops! you are right. Hypo list as the one used in the actual script is very large with sensitive info. I corrected the example of desired output.

Comment: ok that's cool, thanks! also, what condition causes a new list dictionary key to be used? I mean, in the result `{'1A': ['199407'], '101C':['1553678','1851243','1749201']}` why does `'1A'` only have one value in its list `['199407']`, and `'101C'` has multiple values in its list `'101C':['1553678', '1851243','1749201']}`. What condition tells it to not append to the current key, but use a new key?

Comment: @downshift I'm using isdigit() to exclude anything with an alpha character. All keys have alpha character at end. Values are anything that int(item.isdigit()) > 100000. These are account numbers (all are 6 digits or greater) and the only other numbers are parts of address info (street number or zipcode, always less than 100000).

Comment: Hey @ShaunO, I think I've got it working in very few lines of code. I'll post as an answer to get your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keys = ['DATE', 'NAME', 'RT', '1A', '541', '09947', '199407', '552', '09949', 'BOON', \
        '101C', 'SMITH', '00321', '1553678', '1851243', '561', '559', '004789', '1749201', 'ANDERSON']

from collections import OrderedDict

valList = OrderedDict()

for k in keys:
    if len(k) > 0:
        if k[0].isdigit() and k[-1].isalpha() and ' ' not in k and k not in valList.keys():
            valList[k] = []
        try:
            if int(k) > 100000:
                try:
                    valList[valList.keys()[-1]].append(k)
                except ValueError:
                    valList[valList.keys()[-1]] = k
        except ValueError:
            continue

print valList
```

output:

```
OrderedDict([('1Y', ['15538870', '15922112', '16037395', '16069918', '16116102', '16292996', '16658378', '16700710', '16783588', '16832641', '16944735', '16994444', '313132', '12722185', '11415965', '10966593', '9983979', '8573715', '11733178', '552204', '3150537', '552422', '8013132', '9298415', '8742458', '8626402', '4708497', '11687768', '12192686', '734061', '734171', '9896029', '8636757', '2662814', '10407886', '11730755', '4504371', '9187313', '2362896', '7891338', '3519990', '12293652', '9226220', '5984854', '3295145', '1068579', '2031247', '11242586', '8408050', '8440673', '2752194', '5843333', '1740045', '2584772']), ('2A', ['16174735', '16330036', '16334662', '16345573', '16350100', '16376985', '16397823', '16411821', '16435182', '16443451', '16449626', '16574945', '16590154', '16597759', '16615837', '16649016', '16756921', '16762759', '16795828', '16879043', '16887968', '16900090', '16900428', '16902522', '16910127']), ('3A', ['16320336', '16328934', '16331684', '16346347', '16360892', '16370045', '16407413', '16408287', '16444990', '16446211', '16453706', '16467695', '16468032', '11697249', '11843287', '1339389', '2435865', '10001948', '4760965', '2480063', '13588296', '1813233', '11741885', '8972714', '9688478', '16070245']), ('3Y', ['13226120', '13232404', '13233834', '13235601', '13238679', '13241985', '13247504', '13249817', '13262823', '13268442', '13269981', '13270318', '13272413', '13282003', '13284535', '13288943', '13294453'])])
```

or inspect each dictionary one at a time to confirm we get the expected dictionary keys and items:

```
for d in valList.items():
    print d

OrderedDict([
('1Y', ['15538870', '15922112', '16037395', '16069918', '16116102', '16292996', '16658378', '16700710', '16783588', '16832641', '16944735', '16994444', '313132', '12722185', '11415965', '10966593', '9983979', '8573715', '11733178', '552204', '3150537', '552422', '8013132', '9298415', '8742458', '8626402', '4708497', '11687768', '12192686', '734061', '734171', '9896029', '8636757', '2662814', '10407886', '11730755', '4504371', '9187313', '2362896', '7891338', '3519990', '12293652', '9226220', '5984854', '3295145', '1068579', '2031247', '11242586', '8408050', '8440673', '2752194', '5843333', '1740045', '2584772']), ('2A', ['16174735', '16330036', '16334662', '16345573', '16350100', '16376985', '16397823', '16411821', '16435182', '16443451', '16449626', '16574945', '16590154', '16597759', '16615837', '16649016', '16756921', '16762759', '16795828', '16879043', '16887968', '16900090', '16900428', '16902522', '16910127']), ('3A', ['16320336', '16328934', '16331684', '16346347', '16360892', '16370045', '16407413', '16408287', '16444990', '16446211', '16453706', '16467695', '16468032', '11697249', '11843287', '1339389', '2435865', '10001948', '4760965', '2480063', '13588296', '1813233', '11741885', '8972714', '9688478', '16070245']), ('3Y', ['13226120', '13232404', '13233834', '13235601', '13238679', '13241985', '13247504', '13249817', '13262823', '13268442', '13269981', '13270318', '13272413', '13282003', '13284535', '13288943', '13294453'])])
('1Y', ['15538870', '15922112', '16037395', '16069918', '16116102', '16292996', '16658378', '16700710', '16783588', '16832641', '16944735', '16994444', '313132', '12722185', '11415965', '10966593', '9983979', '8573715', '11733178', '552204', '3150537', '552422', '8013132', '9298415', '8742458', '8626402', '4708497', '11687768', '12192686', '734061', '734171', '9896029', '8636757', '2662814', '10407886', '11730755', '4504371', '9187313', '2362896', '7891338', '3519990', '12293652', '9226220', '5984854', '3295145', '1068579', '2031247', '11242586', '8408050', '8440673', '2752194', '5843333', '1740045', '2584772'])
('2A', ['16174735', '16330036', '16334662', '16345573', '16350100', '16376985', '16397823', '16411821', '16435182', '16443451', '16449626', '16574945', '16590154', '16597759', '16615837', '16649016', '16756921', '16762759', '16795828', '16879043', '16887968', '16900090', '16900428', '16902522', '16910127'])
('3A', ['16320336', '16328934', '16331684', '16346347', '16360892', '16370045', '16407413', '16408287', '16444990', '16446211', '16453706', '16467695', '16468032', '11697249', '11843287', '1339389', '2435865', '10001948', '4760965', '2480063', '13588296', '1813233', '11741885', '8972714', '9688478', '16070245'])
('3Y', ['13226120', '13232404', '13233834', '13235601', '13238679', '13241985', '13247504', '13249817', '13262823', '13268442', '13269981', '13270318', '13272413', '13282003', '13284535', '13288943', '13294453'])
```

Comment: @ downshift your code is building the dict but all the keys' values are empty I think because the actual lines list is not being iterated through to get the values for the keys.

Comment: @ downshift I tried using it by replacing the keys list with the line list and got a string index out of range error.

Comment: Ok, sorry there must be something that I'm still not understanding. I put an example here https://repl.it/repls/EthicalCreativeManta. Would you please try to update the code here https://repl.it/repls/EthicalCreativeManta to show how that's not working? Save your link and share it here if possible. thanks.

Comment: @ downshift. I think it's my list and not your code. I replaced my example code with a snippet of the text from what I am actually working with at the link you provided. Didn't get the error with the example list but then it bombed once I replaced it with the actual production stuff.

Comment: you can see the production list sample on repl2

Comment: Where is repl2? If you need help with it, can you share a link here? You can always delete your comments if you don't want to keep the links here.

Comment: I think it's the same link: https://repl.it/repls/EthicalCreativeManta Do you see a My Repls in the top right corner?

Comment: No sorry, I don't see any changes on that link. If you make changes I think there will be a `/2` or something at the end of the link, like `https://repl.it/repls/EthicalCreativeManta/2` after you make changes, try and click the "share" button (next to the "run" button on the repl page), if it is a new link, copy and paste that link here.

Comment: here it is: https://repl.it/@sob1/EthicalCreativeManta-2. I must have gone back to the original page. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160237/discussion-between-downshift-and-shauno).